# Setting Property in Data Context from Action/Command

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, command

I have a `DataTrigger` in my XAML which is binded to a Property, 'ShowEffect' in my ViewModel class. I also have a button which is binded to a `RelayCommand` (class shown below) that calls a method. In that method, I set 'ShowEffect' to true. However, the `DataTrigger` does not seem to respond; the effect is not shown:

I declare the Property using:

```
private Boolean _ShowEffect;
    public Boolean ShowEffect
    {
        get { return _ShowEffect; }
        set { _ShowEffect = value; }
    }
```

**`RelayCommand` Class:**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
}
```

I'm wondering whether the issue is related to the dispatcher. Can anyone suggest why the binding isn't working when I set the property in the method called by the command? It works when I set the property anywhere else in  the ViewModel.

Comment: your VM needs to implement INPC if it doesn't already and `ShowEffect` needs to Raise the propertychanged handler when it's changed(from it's setter when value changes) for changes made to it to be recognized by the View. What you got right now is a simple property which will not notify view of any updates made to it which is prolly what's happening when the command changes it's value but the view never gets to know about the change and your `DataTrigger` seems to not work.

Comment: @Viv + 1 Ah, thank you. Adding `NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowEffect")` in the property setter solved it! Do you want to add an answer so that I can accept seeing as though you were first?

Comment: @Viv Just edited previous comment :)

Comment: You're welcome :) and did add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting previous comment to an answer.

> your VM needs to implement INPC if it doesn't already and ShowEffect needs to Raise the propertychanged handler when it's changed(from it's setter when value changes) for changes made to it to be recognized by the View. What you got right now is a simple property which will not notify view of any updates made to it which is prolly what's happening when the command changes it's value but the view never gets to know about the change and your DataTrigger seems to not work.

[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface is what informs the View a property in the VM has changed. Hence your property needs to raise the PropertyChanged handler for it to thereby inform the view of any changes made to it.